# I am always confused where to put the javascript in rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

is it through the javascript_include_tag in content for: head section or somewhere else , whats the best practice to do the same ,what are the various pro's and cons of each approach

Answer (score 1):

The best way is put js files in app/assets/javascripts
so they will auto added with application.js file, line "//= require_tree ."
for More details you could read here http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html